# Converting String Format Date for Date Object

Tags: java, date, string-to-datetime

I am getting a Date format in String as Output like this.

> Fri May 18 00:00:00 EDT 2012

I need to Convert this to a Date Object. What approach shall I use?

Thank you.

This is the program i used.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class DateToString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            DateFormat formatter ;
            Date date ;
            formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'EDT' yyyy ");
            date = (Date)formatter.parse("Fri May 18 00:00:00 EDT 2012");
            String s = formatter.format(date);
            System.out.println("Today is " + s);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception :"+e); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and implementations to get a date displayable in a format you want.

**Example**:

```
String myDateString = "Fri May 18 00:00:00 EDT 2012";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();
dateFormat.applyPattern( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy" );

try {
    Date d = dateFormat.parse( myDateString );
    System.out.println( d ); // Fri May 18 00:00:00 EDT 2012

    String datePattern1 = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    dateFormat.applyPattern( datePattern1 );
    System.out.println( dateFormat.format( d ) ); // 2012-05-18

    String datePattern2 = "yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z";
    dateFormat.applyPattern( datePattern2 );
    System.out.println( dateFormat.format( d ) ); // 2012.05.18 AD at 00:00:00 EDT

    String datePattern3 = "yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss Z";
    dateFormat.applyPattern( datePattern3 );
    System.out.println( dateFormat.format( d ) ); // 2012.05.18 AD at 00:00:00 -400
}
catch ( Exception e ) { // ParseException
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Well here you formattin the Date. I have the "d" as string not as date object

Comment: @user1422029 `System.out.println( "Thanks This is Working Perfect".equals( "answerAccepted" ) ); // false`

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at: [java.text.SimpleDateFormat Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
SimpleDateFormat dateParser = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy", 
    Locale.US);
Date date = dateParser.parse("Fri May 18 00:00:00 EDT 2012");
```

**Update:** note to self, locale can be important.

Comment: <code>
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
public class DateToString {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 try {
 DateFormat formatter ; 
 Date date ;  
  formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'EDT' yyyy ");
  date = (Date)formatter.parse("Fri May 18 00:00:00 EDT 2012");  
  String s = formatter.format(date);
  System.out.println("Today is " + s);
  } catch (ParseException e)
  {System.out.println("Exception :"+e);  }  
 
 }
}
</code>

Comment: Have to specify locale, I updated the answer with this earlier.

Comment: Specify GMT timezone I think?

Comment: I can't vouch for your code as it is not doing the same thing as I have listed here, you have another format string in the code you pasted here @Azar ... You seem to have mixed it up with someones elses code and now accepted an answer that was made an hour later with my exact code :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) with the following pattern:

```
EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'EDT' YYYY
```

This doesn't worry about Timezone, Alternatively, with timezone inclusion: (*untested*) `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z YYYY` (it's a lowercase `z`). Bear in mind, I haven't tested it yet (as I'm on my way home from work).

Comment: That would parse `EDT` literally, and not as the timezone specifier, wouldn't it?

Comment: [code] import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
public class DateToString {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 try {
 DateFormat formatter ; 
 Date date ;  
  formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'EDT' yyyy ");
  date = (Date)formatter.parse("Fri May 18 00:00:00 EDT 2012");  
  String s = formatter.format(date);
  System.out.println("Today is " + s);
  } catch (ParseException e)
  {System.out.println("Exception :"+e);  }  
 
 }
}

Comment: @aix, yes, that's because I was trying to figure out between `z` and `Z`.

Comment: @user1422029, the comment section is **not** the place to paste code. Update your post, if you will.

Comment: @user1422029 Please update your question with your code and tell us what exactly isn't working. Show exception stacktrace if applicable.

Comment: @user1422029, please post the **stacktrace** if you want us to understand your error. Did you use my 2nd pattern (the one that include timezone)?

Comment: ---------- java ----------
Exception :java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri May 18 00:00:00 EDT 2012"